# How Can I shift the entire view including the picker view Upward on keyboard appearence

Tags: swift

I have this situation where I have a pickerView as a toolbar with searchbar above a pickerView. Now when I tap on searchbar the keyboard appears and i want the pickerView including the toolbar to move up.

Here is some code of pickerView -

```
  var picker = UIPickerView()
  picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 216))  
  picker.delegate = self
  picker.dataSource = self
  tfCountry.inputView = picker
  tfCountry.inputView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.82)
        
  searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 20)
  searchBar.placeholder = "Search Country"
  let leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)
  searchBar.delegate = self
  searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
  searchBar.sizeToFit()
            
  let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0))
  toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.82)
  toolBar.sizeToFit()
 toolBar.setItems([leftNavBarButton], animated: false)
 tfCountry.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

tfCountry is the name of the textfield that triggers the pickerView. I anybody could help me i would appreciate it.

I tried shifting the entire view up. And it looks line in the photo below.

[sample image of up lifiting view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROl1p.jpg)

In this photo the picker view still remains at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you'll need to receive a notification for when the keyboard has become visible**

We do this by adding a [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) anywhere in the app, which will listen to a specific change (in this case the keyboard showing / hiding event). Which we can then subscribe to in order to change the position of the view. (seen further down)

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

**NOTE:** It is recommended to also remove these Notifications after you are done with them to avoid memory leaks / performance issues. This is similar syntax but instead we use `removeObserver` followed by the notification name. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver)

**Next, we can listen to when this notification has been triggered**

```
//Ideally this would be in your view
//You'll want to use a scrollView so we can easily scroll to the content when it is covered by the keyboard
//This scrollView will have to be added to your parent view or whatever structure you are using
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
//The target for the scroll
let textField = UITextField()
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
  //Should be disabled by default
  self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
  
  //An object containing information about the keyboard event
  if let info = notification.userInfo {
    //We'll need the keyboard size in order to know how much to bump the view by
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
   
    guard keyboardSize != nil else { return }
    
    //New view height now determined on the height of the keyboard
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
    
    //Adding these positions to the scrollView, you will have to keep in mind where your UIPickerView is and where you want it to be when the keyboard is visible, but this example should be similar to what you need to achieve 
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    
    //Get frame object
    let rect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    //make height size of frame - keyboard
    rect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    //Check if textField exists
    if let activeField = self.textField {
      //If it does and the frame contains the textField, scroll to it
      if (!rect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
        self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
      }
   }

}
```

**Lastly, do the opposite when the keyboard disappear to replace the view back to normal**

As before you'll need to create a function to receive the keyboard being hidden event:

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
```

I'll let you try that one on your own ;)

For more info, check the docs on managing the keyboard [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)